# How To Build a Simple Carousel With Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning plain js try the carousel slider if anyone knows please help

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+To+Build+a+Simple+Carousel+With+Vanilla+JavaScript

Comment: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-simple-carousel-with-vanilla-javascript--cms-41734

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply be [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=create%20carousel%20with%20vanilla%20codepen&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=AJOqlzUQ1140ww4xDYDSG3luTfZafp1H_Q%3A1678526887201&ei=p0kMZLDsC8GV3LUPivKkkAM&oq=create%20carousel%20with%20vanila%20code&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAxgAMgcIIRCgARAKOgQIABBHOgQIIRAKOgYIIRAVEApKBAhBGABQdFj_EWDcGGgAcAJ4AYABggOIAaoKkgEHMC4yLjIuMZgBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp) and get the answers from google itself.

one solution as follows...

```js
// Variables
let prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
let next = document.querySelector('.next');
let imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-img');
let dots = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
let captions = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-caption')
let totalImgs = imgs.length;
let imgPosition = 0;

// Event Listeners
next.addEventListener('click', nextImg);
prev.addEventListener('click', prevImg);

// Update Position
function updatePosition (){
//   Images
  for(let img of imgs){
    img.classList.remove('visible');
    img.classList.add('hidden');
  }
  imgs[imgPosition].classList.remove('hidden');
  imgs[imgPosition].classList.add('visible')
//   Dots
  for (let dot of dots) {
     dot.className = dot.className.replace(" active", "");
  }
    dots[imgPosition].classList.add('active');
//   Captions
  for (let caption of captions) {
      caption.classList.remove('visible');
      caption.classList.add('hidden');
  }
    captions[imgPosition].classList.remove('hidden');
    captions[imgPosition].classList.add('visible')
}

// Next Img
function nextImg(){
  if (imgPosition === totalImgs -1){
        imgPosition = 0;
    } else{
        imgPosition++;
    }
    updatePosition();
}
//Previous Image
function prevImg(){
  if (imgPosition === 0){
        imgPosition = totalImgs-1;
    } else{
        imgPosition--;
    }
    updatePosition();
}

// Dot Position
dots.forEach((dot, dotPosition) => {
  dot.addEventListener("click", () => {
    imgPosition = dotPosition
    updatePosition(dotPosition)
  })
})
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
}

.carousel-container{
  position:relative;
  margin:1em auto .5em auto;
  max-width:400px;
}
.carousel-container, .carousel-caption{
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(204,204,204);;
}
.carousel-container img{
border-radius:.5em;
  width: 400px;
}
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
.visible{
  display:block;
}
.arrow{
  display:inline;
}

.prev, .arrow{
 cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin: -1.5em .3em 0 .3em;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  border-radius: .5em;
  user-select: none;
  background-color:rgba(204,204,204, 0.3);
}
.next {
  right:0 ;
}
.prev:hover, .next:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
  border:1px solid #fff;
}
.slide-numbers{
  text-align: center;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:1em;
  left:45%;

}
.dot{
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: rgba(204,204,204, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
} 

.dot:hover, .active{
  background-color: rgb(204,204,204);
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
}
.dot:hover{
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
}
.carousel-caption{
  text-align: center;
  font-family:'Nanum Gothic',serif;
  background-color: rgba(204,204,204,.8);
  max-width:400px;
  margin:.5em auto;
  padding:1em 0;
  border-radius:.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
  <div class="carousel-imgs">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/3rCW1xj.png" class="carousel-img visible"/>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AsXzjqX.png" class="carousel-img  hidden"/>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/aJndu7X.png" class="carousel-img  hidden"/>
  </div>
    <a class="prev arrow">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next arrow">&#10095;</a>
  <div class="slide-numbers">
      <span class="dot active"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
  </div>
  
</div>
<div class="carousel-captions">
  <p class="carousel-caption visible">Mountain Range 1</p>
  <p class="carousel-caption hidden">Mountain Range 2</p>
  <p class="carousel-caption hidden">Mountain Range 3</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-wrapper">
    <div class="carousel-item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="carousel-item">Item 3</div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-prev">Prev</button>
  <button class="carousel-next">Next</button>
</div>

<style>
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.carousel-item {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.carousel-prev,
.carousel-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel-prev {
  left: 0;
}

.carousel-next {
  right: 0;
}
</style>

<script>
const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
const wrapper = carousel.querySelector('.carousel-wrapper');
const prevButton = carousel.querySelector('.carousel-prev');
const nextButton = carousel.querySelector('.carousel-next');
const items = carousel.querySelectorAll('.carousel-item');
const itemWidth = items[0].offsetWidth;

let currentPosition = 0;

function slideTo(position) {
  if (position > 0 || position < -(items.length - 1) * itemWidth) {
    return;
  }

  currentPosition = position;
  wrapper.style.transform = `translateX(${position}px)`;
}

prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => slideTo(currentPosition + itemWidth));
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => slideTo(currentPosition - itemWidth));
</script>
```

You should give more information in your request of at least showing SOME SORT of effort in learning or people wont be inclined to help you out bud.